# SharePoint2013 Custom Field Type: getElementById doesn't work when textbox's ClientIDMode set to AutoID

Tags: sharepoint-2013, custom-field-type

I created a Custom Field Type with one textbox and one button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextField" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"  ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:Button ID="TreeButton" Text="..." runat="server" onclientclick="HandlePopupResult();" />
```

on button click , I call a javascript function (HandlePopupResult) to set a resultValue to textbox .

```
function HandlePopupResult(resultValue) {
        document.getElementById('TextField').value = resultValue; }
```

If I set `ClientIDMode` of `'TextField'` to `static` , this code worked, but when I set it to `AutoID` the `HandlePopupResult` function doesn't work .

I set `ClientIDMode="AutoId"` of `TextField` and  used

```
document.getElementById('<%=TextField.ClientID%>').value = resultValue;
```

then I got `UnhandebleException`

Trying  to browse NewForm of each lists that has one field as type of my custom field.

It is necessery that my `TextField CleintIDMode` be `AutoId` and I can set value of textfield
I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot and finally  found this sample

http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2011/11/07/walkthrough-custom-field-type-for-uploading-and-displaying-images-in-sharepoint-2010-lists/

this sample solved my problem by new way of getting controls clientId .